# Partially color table cell compatiable with IE-8

Tags: css, html-table, ie8-compatibility-mode

Please visit: [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/vdCsJ4x9vxnykGwLh74s?p=preview)

```
<table id="customers">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Sales</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12%</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
.... ....
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to partially fill color in the cells of "Sales" colomn, according to the percentage, with IE-8 compatibility.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jquery to achieve this. Look at the following jquery. I am taking the td value and assign it for the div with background color.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    
   $("#customers tr td:first-child").each(function(){        
    var textval = "<div class='bg' style='width:"+$(this).html()+"'>&nbsp;</div>";        
    $(this).html(textval);
   });
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x44K3/)

Comment: But this does not show the text: like, 12%, 18.6% etc the actual percentages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#customers').each(function(){
if ($(this) >= 0% && $(this) <= 25%) {
              $(this).css('background-color','gray');
    }else if ($(this) >= 25% && $(this) <= 50%) {
              $(this).css('background-color','red');
    }else if ($(this) >= 50% && $(this) <= 75%) {
              $(this).css('background-color','red');
    }else if ($(this) >= 75% && $(this) <= 100%) {
              $(this).css('background-color','green');
    }
});
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="customers">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Sales</th>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12%</td>
<td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
<td>Maria Anders</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</tr>
.... ....
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery for this. Conditional formatting *(like Excel)*, see [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066882/conditional-formatting-of-html-table-cells).